# Inboud rules for https is not accepting in aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2

I'm not able to make Inbound rules of https in aws ec2, because I have to make force http to https redirection. http://example.com to https://example.com.

Here is my Virtual Host file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP-X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://example.io [L,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

try with following steps

1. Allow 80 and 443 port in inbound rule of concernd security group.
2. Add following code in httpd.conf file then remove old code you have written for the redirection

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: I have written Rewrite rule as you told getting this error  "redirected you too many times."

Comment: remove rest of the rewrite rules

Comment: I have removed all the Rewrite rule and just kept as you told, also shall I remove rewrite from .htaccess

Comment: yes remove code from .htaccess file.  just cross check again httpd.conf file only having this rewrite rule.

Comment: I don't have httpd.conf file but I have /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf, I'm changing in 000-default.conf